# AIML not printing anything within this one condition loop; XCAR in nested category inside that condition loop treating input sentence as a single word

Tags: aiml, pandorabots

Using [the standard library](https://github.com/pandorabots/aiml-utilities/blob/master/lib/aimlstandardlibrary.aiml).

The code looks like `<srai>XCAR AB, CD</srai>`

But the stack trace shows `[0] srai of XCAR AB,CD` with the space removed.

Using [Pandorabots.com](https://www.pandorabots.com).

I'm trying to loop though a string of `,` -delineated words of uniform length using XSUBSTRING, in order to map each one to a human-readable output.

So I'm using a nested category to get and print the XCAR of each XSUBSTRING based on the updated index predicate from the outer category.

Here's the code for the outer category:

```
<category>
    <pattern>COMMAND</pattern>
    <template>
        <think>
            <set name="index">0</set>
            <set name="allitemsprinted">FALSE</set>
        </think>
        
        This part prints for me.
        <br/><br/>
        So does this.
        
        <!-- iterate through "ties" -->
        <condition name="allitemsprinted" value="FALSE">
            But this doesn't print.
            Nor does anything after.
            This srai works correctly:
            <srai>XCDR UX, SE, CS</srai>
            <srai>PRINT ITEM</srai>
            <loop/>
        </condition>
        
        <br/>
    </template>
</category>
```

And here's the nested category:

```
<category>
    <pattern>PRINT ITEM</pattern>
    <template>
        <think>
            <set var="itemlocation">
                <!-- 2-char name plus delim -->
                <srai>XMUL <get name="index"/> XS 4</srai>
            </set>
            
            <set var="remainingitems">
                <srai>XSUBSTRING <get name="items"/> XS <get var="itemlocation"/></srai>
            </set>
            
            <!-- increment index -->
            <set name="index">
                <map name="successor">
                    <get name="index"/>
                </map>
            </set>
            
            <!-- check for end of list -->
            <set name="allitemsprinted">
                <srai>XGT <get name="index"/> XS <get name="itemcount"/></srai>
            </set>
        </think>
        
        Remaining items: <get var="remainingitems"/>
        
        First remaining item: <srai>XCAR <get var="remainingitems"/></srai>
        
        <!-- human-readable output -->
        <map name="itemsreadable">
            <srai>XCAR <get var="remainingitems"/></srai>
        </map>
        <br/>
    </template>
</category>
```

The stack trace provided by Pandorabots shows that the `<srai>` inside the `<condition>` does indeed get called. But it won't print anything at all.

Comment: XCAR returns the first word in a string. Check your normal.substitution file. Do you have an entry like this [", ",","]? It looks like you are removing the space after the comma. I tried XCAR AB, CD and it correctly returns AB,

Comment: @SteveWorswick No, I don't see an entry containing either `", "` or `","` in my `normal.substitution`.

Comment: Try this category and say TEST AB, CD. Does it say, "AB, CD" or "AB,CD"?    <category>
        <pattern>TEST *</pattern>
        <template><star/></template>
    </category>

Comment: @SteveWorswick Yes, the XCAR and XCDR both work properly in a standalone category. So I'm adding some additional context to OP and considering rephrasing the title...

Comment: Are you able to post your category so we can see where it's going wrong?

Comment: @SteveWorswick Yes, code added, with apologies for my improper html-style indents for my own readability...

Comment: Just so I understand, you have a list of things like UX, SE, CS and are trying to map each one so it displays an entry in a map like User Experience,  Sales Entry, Customer Services?

Comment: @SteveWorswick that is correct, yes!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make sure normal.substitution has an entry for removing commas `[",", ""],` as it's very rare that the bot needs to process commas.

Assuming your map is something like this:

```
[
    ["UX", "User Experience"], 
    ["SE", "Sales Entry"], 
    ["CS", "Customer Services"]
]
```

You can then do this to get human readable output (you don't need the standard library for this):

```
<category>
    <pattern>COMMAND</pattern>
    <template>
        <think><set name="itemlist">UX, SE, CS</set></think>
        <srai>PRINT ITEM <get name="itemlist"/></srai>
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>PRINT ITEM * *</pattern>
    <template>
        <map name="itemsreadable"><star/></map><br/>
        <srai>PRINT ITEM <star index="2"/></srai>
    </template>
</category>

<category>
    <pattern>PRINT ITEM *</pattern>
    <template>
        <map name="itemsreadable"><star/></map>
    </template>
</category>
```

This will produce the following:

[image]

Comment: Well, look at me, overcomplicating things! I will test your solution shortly, my friend, but I feel quite sure about it at a glance. Much obliged for your time!